# Android 10. MediaStore DATE_TAKEN returns always null

Tags: android, kotlin, mediastore, android-10.0

I have problem in Android 10.

DATE_TAKEN returns normal value when I take a picture on default camera application.

but it always return null when I insert image on my code.

What should I do to get normal DATE_TAKEN value?

// when read

```
val cursor = context!!.contentResolver.query(data, null, null, null, null, null)
val date_taken = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN))
Toast.makeText(context, date_taken, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

// save code

```
val now = System.currentTimeMillis()

val value = ContentValues().apply {
  put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, DCIM/customPath)
  put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "image.jpeg")
  put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/*")
  put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, now / 1000)
  put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, now)
  put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 1)
}

val item: Uri = contentResolver.insert(collection, value)!!

try {
  val pdf = contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(item, "w", null)

  if (pdf != null) {
    val inputStream = getImageInputStream(agreePaper2)
    val strToByte = getBytes(inputStream)
    FileOutputStream(pdf.fileDescriptor).use { it.write(strToByte) }
    inputStream.close()
    pdf.close()
    contentResolver.update(item, value, null, null)
  }
} catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
  e.printStackTrace()
} catch (e: IOException) {
  e.printStackTrace()
}

value.clear()
value.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 0)
contentResolver.update(item, value, null, null)
```

// getImageInputStream

```
private fun getImageInputStream(bitmap: Bitmap): InputStream {
  val bytes = ByteArrayOutputStream()
  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes)
  val bitmapData = bytes.toByteArray()

  return ByteArrayInputStream(bitmapData)
}
```

// getBytes

```
private fun getBytes(inputStream: InputStream): ByteArray {
  val byteBuffer = ByteArrayOutputStream()
  val bufferSize = 1024
  val buffer = ByteArray(bufferSize)

  var len = inputStream.read(buffer)

  while (len != -1) {
    byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
    len = inputStream.read(buffer)
  }

  return byteBuffer.toByteArray()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I can think of is that you have to first move to at least the first entry in the cursor by `cursor.movetoFirst()`

Also you don't have to set `DATE_ADDED` as it will be overwritten by [MediaProvider](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/MediaProvider/+/refs/heads/master/src/com/android/providers/media/MediaProvider.java). You do not need to update the second time in the try-catch-block.